# Разная толщина у линий тега hr

Tags: html, css, теги

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему у линий `<hr>` разные толщины?

```css
h2 {}

label {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  background: gray;
  height: 1px;
}

.field {
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.main {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Surname:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Login:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>Man<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Man"> Woman<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Woman"></div>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ctrl-0 пробовали?

Comment: Не знаю, что это

Comment: Выглядит как будто у вас в браузере масштаб не 100%

Comment: У вас 150% масштаб стоит в браузере. Зажмите Ctrl и покрутите колесико на мышке, или нажмите Ctrl и 0, чтобы вернуть 100% масштаб.

Comment: Масштаб 100%. Эту часть страницы я вырезал для наглядности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, вы играетесь с масштабом, поэтому и ловите изменение толщины линий. Тема достаточно обширна, в плане отрисовки браузерами различных свойств, плотности и количества пикселей. Если вам интересно решение именно этого вопроса, то замените фон на линию границы:

```
border-top: 1px gray solid;
```

```css
h2 {}

label {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px gray solid;
}

.field {
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.main {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Surname:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Login:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>Man<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Man"> Woman<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Woman"></div>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разная толщина это графический баг полупикселей. У меня он проявился если увеличить масштаб страницы до 125%.

Я бы сделал так:

```
hr {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
hr {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #f0f;
  /* old IE */
  background-color: #f0f;
  /* Modern Browsers */
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, как это отвечает на вопрос

Comment: Перейди на сайт и почитай (qaru.site/questions/32993/how-i-change-the-thickness-of-my-hr-tag)

Comment: Пробовал так. Не помогает

Comment: @LuricSapi перешёл, почитал. В коде автора вопроса тоже прописана высота и тоже указан цвет фона. Вы в ответе написали то же самое. Но проблемы это не решает. Всё ещё непонятно, как это отвечает на вопрос

Comment: Попробуй <hr noshade> , или почитай на (shad-55.narod.ru/html/content/color.html)